# Is there an ARM template which will allow us to setup a MongoDB replica set instance using Azure Managed Disk instead of regular data disks

Tags: mongodb, azure-managed-disk

Is there an ARM template which will allow us to setup a MongoDB replica set instance using Azure Managed Disk instead of regular data disks?

Note: The following reference provides a way to setup MongoDB replica set using regular data disks

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/mongodb-replica-set-centos/nested/primary-resources.json#L190-L230

Answer (score 0):

You can edit [the ARM template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/mongodb-replica-set-centos/nested/primary-resources.json#L190-L230) to use Managed Disks as shown below. Also, please use the apiVersion as 2017-03-30

"apiVersion": "**2017-03-30**",

"type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",

```
     {

          "name": "datadisk1",

          "diskSizeGB": "[parameters('sizeOfDataDiskInGB')]",

          "lun": 0,

          "createOption": "Empty",

          "managedDisk": {
              "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS"
            }

          "caching": "ReadWrite"

      }
```